# Embedded Python code in a Windows shell command

Tags: c, windows, python-2.7, command-line, arguments

How can I embed a small Python script into a Windows shell command to provide arguments to a program?

Example:

```
C:\> hello Bob
Welcome Bob!
```

What I need is something like this:

```
C:\> hello 'python -c print('Bob')'
Welcome Bob!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell supports the same format as bash, so you can do:

```
PS C:\> hello $(python -c "print('Bob')")
```

For `cmd.exe`, there is no such equivalent, but you can try this (untested):

```
C:\>FOR /F "usebackq" %x in (`python -c "print('Bob')"`) DO hello %x
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks